Delete non-Yahoo mail accounts from Yahoo mail
I have some external (not Yahoo) mail accounts being checked via POP in Yahoo Mail.  I no longer have these external accounts and would like to delete them from my Yahoo account.  Under 'manage accounts' they are not shown, only my Yahoo accounts are shown.
The accounts that need to be deleted aren't Yahoo accounts.
How do I delete them?

Welcome to Web Applications. Consider registering your account to avoid accidentally losing access to your content by switching devices, browsers, or clearing your cookies. Registering is quick and you gain access to more site features. For more info see Why should I register my account?

According to Yahoo ! help:
Manage third-party email addresses within Yahoo Mail

Click Settings  then More Settings.
Click Mailboxes.
Select the account you'd like to disconnect.
Click Remove mailbox.
Click Remove mailbox again to confirm.

